Объясните, пожалуйста, пунктуацию в этом предложении
Касательно Алгоритма по масштабированию интеграции медицинских информационных систем с призывными пунктами проводится работа по обеспечению призывных (сборных) пунктов необходимой компьютерной и периферийной техникой с подключением медицинских призывных комиссий к медицинским информационным системам.

Вопрос надо сформулировать. Если есть сомнения в каких-либо знаках, укажите на них.
